# Chrome using more than 100% CPU on YouTube?

Tags: google-chrome, youtube, cpu-load

I'am new to Ubuntu and I'am trying the 14.04 LTS version.

When I am seeing any video on Chrome, my computer suddenly gets real slow, so I opened Chrome's task manager...

[image: Task manager 1]

[image: Task manager 2]

Why is this happening?

**EDIT:** I am using the HTML5 player

**EDIT 2:** `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` output:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 181b
Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 650M] (rev ff)
08:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229    PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 1818
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Edit /etc/modprobe.d/local.conf
2. Add the following line:

   *options drm_kms_helper poll=N*
3. Restart and problems are gone (at least for me with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS).

Credits to [this link](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1921292.html).

Comment: Have the same issue as described in answer, but this doesn't fix the issue :(  I'm on ubuntu 16.04